# Is it possible to make a Partitioned table Non-partitioned in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given there is a Partitioned table in BigQuery, is it possible to make it non-partitioned?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no feature/function to unpartition a partitioned table. However, there's nothing stopping you doing a `select * from partitioned_table` and writing to results to a new (non-partitioned table). Using this approach you'll of course take a hit on cost.

Another way could be to export your table(s) to GCS and then load the exported file(s) back in. Loading doesn't cost anything, so you'd only pay for the brief amount of time the files are stored in GCS.

Comment: @GrahamPolley - did you have chance to check my answer? what you think? I tested - it worked for me

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - yup, very clever way of doing. Upvoted. The bq cli tool also works for copying - `bq cp -a ....`. Although, the table that I tested with (3TB) took 1 hour to copy!

Comment: @corgrath - see Mickhails answer too. This is great way to not incur any charges. The only downside is it takes quite some time to copy the partitioned table.

Comment: @GrahamPolley - Thank you Graham. That's interesting stats. How long it took to do with `select * from partitioned_table` into new table approach? In case if you had chance to test?

Comment: ~5 minutes using `select * from..`

Comment: makes sense  - time is money - 5 min for $60 or 1 hour for free :o)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a Partitioned table Non-partitioned in BigQuery?

It is possible!! Quick and Free ($0.00)

**Step 1** - Create new non-partitioned table with exact same schema as your source table and no rows

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `xxx.yyy.your_partitioned_table`
WHERE FALSE
```

run above with destination - `xxx.yyy.your_new_NON_PARTITIONED_table`

**Step 2** - Invoke Copy job with WRITE_APPEND as a writeDisposition

Your copy config will look like below

```sql
{
    "configuration": {
        "copy": {
            "sourceTable": {
                "projectId": "xxx",
                "datasetId": "yyy",
                "tableId": "your_partitioned_table"
            },
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": "xxx",
                "datasetId": "yyy",
                "tableId": "your_new_NON_PARTITIONED_table"
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND"
        }
    }
}
```

Mission accomplished!
Note: Both steps are free of charge!